# Expecting Time.zone.parse to raise error with invalid date but return nil

Tags: parsing, ruby-on-rails-4, exception, timezone

Why doesn't `Time.zone.parse('invalid')` raise an error while `Time.parse('invalid')` does ?

---

Example using Rails 4.2.7.1

```
>> Time.zone.parse('invalid')
nil

>> Time.parse('invalid')
ArgumentError: no time information in "invalid"
    from D:/softwares/ruby/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/time.rb:252:in `make_time'
    from D:/softwares/ruby/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/time.rb:364:in `parse'
```

Comment: Have a look at the actual source code of the methods and you will understand :) [link1](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Time.html#method-i-zone) and [link2](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-parse)

Comment: Thanks, I understand the behaviour. However I don't understand *why* did they choose to do it this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both methods call `Date._parse` which return `{}` if no date could be extracted.

`Time.zone.parse` stops there and returns if the result is empty.
`Time.parse` makes a call to `make_time` which throws an error if no date could be generated.